# An urn with 32 balls where $5\choose r$ are labelled with the number $r$ (for $r=0,1,2,3,4,5$).

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose we choose randomly and without replacement 3 balls from the urn, and let $S$ be the sum of the numbers written on these 3 chosen balls then what what is the expectation value of $S$, i.e. $E(S)$?

Do I actually need to write every possible option for the sum $S$ and then multiply by a suitable probability?. For example for $S=0+1+2=3$ we have the probability is $(1/32)\times 5\times (1/31)\times 10 \times (1/30)$, and then do the same for the other options of numbers.

Seems like a lot of work, is there a shortcut I don't see?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you draw $1$ ball, the expected value is $2.5$ (as you can check). Expectation is linear. Which means the sum of three draws (with or without replacement) is simply $3\cdot (2.5)=7.5$

Comment: Except the choosing of the second and third balls is without replacement, which makes it a bit tougher to see that the expected value of the second ball or of the third ball is also 2.5.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Think of drawing all three balls and lining them up but without looking at them. Still without looking at them, what is the expected value of the first ball? The second ball? The third ball? Because expectation is linear, the expected value of the sum is the sum of the expected values. Ok...now you can look at the balls.

Answer (score 3):

There is a symmetry to the problem: whenever there is a possibility $(a, b, c)$ for the values of the three draws, there is another possibility $(5-a, 5-b, 5-c)$ which has equal probability.  Furthermore, if the value of the random variable on $S(a,b,c) = x$, then the value on $S(5-a, 5-b, 5-c) = 15-(a+b+c) = 15-x$.

Now, using this symmetry, we can conclude that $E(S) = 15 - E(S)$.